# Could somebody say what this catalog-dita.xml file is and how could I transform to xml and back?

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I'm updating old DITA-OT and there is file used catalog-dita.txt which contents seems same as catalog-dita.xml - only thing that in newer DITA-OT there is no txt files

catalog-dita.txt:

```
--              (C) Copyright OASIS Open 2005, 2009.               --
--              (C) Copyright IBM Corporation 2001, 2004.          --
--              All Rights Reserved.                               --
--                                                                 --
--   UPDATES:                                                      --
--     2005.11.15 RDA: Corrected system ID for topicAttr.mod       --
--     2005.11.15 RDA: Corrected public ID for tblDecl.mod         --
--     2005.11.15 RDA: Removed @xml:base from <group>              --
--     2006.06.07 RDA: Added commonElements.mod                    --
--     2006.06.07 RDA: Added indexing domain                       --
--     2006.06.20 RDA: Added bookmap and XNAL domain               --
--     2006.11.30 RDA: Added version specific public IDs           --
--     2008.01.25 RDA: Added DITA 1.2 version specific IDs         --
--     2008.02.01 RDA: *.ent files for topic types                 --
--     2008.02.12 RDA: Add hazard statement domain                 --
--     2008.02.13 RDA: Added DITA 1.x PUBLIC IDs                   --
--     2008.04.11 RDA: Added Learning specializations              --
--     2008.04.15 RDA: Added Machine Industry specializations      --
--     2008.04.15 RDA: Reorganized DTDs into subdirectories        --
--     2008.06.03 RDA: Added glossary group, glossary domains      --
--     2008.11.24 RDA: Added ditaval                               --
--     2009.01.05 RDA: Rename machineIndustry dir to machinery     --
--     2009.11.10 RDA: Add entries for glossentry.*                --
--     2009.12.03 RDA: Add entry for learningInteractionBaseDomain --
--     2010.04.08 RDA: Add basemap.dtd and basetopic.dtd           --
--  Catalog for Dita DTDs  --
BASE "base/dtd/" 
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA Topic//EN" "topic.mod"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA 1.x Topic//EN" "topic.mod"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA 1.2 Topic//EN" "topic.mod"

PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Topic Definitions//EN" "topicDefn.ent"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA 1.x Topic Definitions//EN" "topicDefn.ent"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA 1.2 Topic Definitions//EN" "topicDefn.ent"

PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Topic Class//EN" "topicAttr.mod"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA Map//EN" "map.mod"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA 1.x Map//EN" "map.mod"
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA 1.2 Map//EN" "map.mod"
```

catalog-dita.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--             (C) Copyright OASIS Open 2005, 2009.              -->
<!--             (C) Copyright IBM Corporation 2001, 2004.         -->
<!--             All Rights Reserved.                              -->
<!--                                                               -->
<!--  UPDATES:                                                     -->
<!--    2005.11.15 RDA: Corrected system ID for topicAttr.mod      -->
<!--    2005.11.15 RDA: Corrected public ID for tblDecl.mod        -->
<!--    2005.11.15 RDA: Removed @xml:base from <group>             -->
<!--    2006.06.07 RDA: Added commonElements.mod                   -->
<!--    2006.06.07 RDA: Added indexing domain                      -->
<!--    2006.06.20 RDA: Added bookmap and XNAL domain              -->
<!--    2006.11.30 RDA: Added version specific public IDs          -->
<!--    2008.01.25 RDA: Added DITA 1.2 version specific IDs        -->
<!--    2008.02.01 RDA: *.ent files for topic types                -->
<!--    2008.02.12 RDA: Add hazard statement domain                -->
<!--    2008.02.13 RDA: Added DITA 1.x PUBLIC IDs                  -->
<!--    2008.04.11 RDA: Added Learning specializations             -->
<!--    2008.04.15 RDA: Added Machine Industry specializations     -->
<!--    2008.04.15 RDA: Reorganized DTDs into subdirectories       -->
<!--    2008.06.03 RDA: Added glossary group, glossary domains     -->
<!--    2008.11.24 RDA: Added ditaval                              -->
<!--    2009.01.05 RDA: Rename machineIndustry dir to machinery    -->
<!--    2009.11.10 RDA: Add entries for glossentry.*               -->
<!--    2009.12.03 RDA: Add entry for learningInteractionBaseDomain -->
<!--    2010.04.08 RDA: Add basemap.dtd and basetopic.dtd          -->

<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"
         prefer="public">

<!-- Catalog for Dita DTDs -->

  <group xml:base="base/dtd/">
    <!-- Topics -->
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA Topic//EN"
            uri="topic.mod"/>
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA 1.x Topic//EN"
            uri="topic.mod"/>
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ELEMENTS DITA 1.2 Topic//EN"
            uri="topic.mod"/>
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Topic Definitions//EN"
            uri="topicDefn.ent"/>
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA 1.x Topic Definitions//EN"
            uri="topicDefn.ent"/>
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA 1.2 Topic Definitions//EN"
            uri="topicDefn.ent"/>
    <!-- topicAttr.mod is only used in DITA 1.0; kept for backwards compatibility -->
    <public publicId="-//OASIS//ENTITIES DITA Topic Class//EN"
            uri="topicAttr.mod"/>
```

Could somebody say what this txt file is? What format it is? Easiest would be to transform the new xml to txt if there would be such tools.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's just a text representation of the XML catalog. It has not been included since (I believe) 2.0 (current version is 3.3.4).